# Tengo problemas con hibernate hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

Tags: java, netbeans, hibernate

hace poco comencé a aprender hibernate y me surgio el siguiente error, que ha de ser muy simple pero la verdad no le encuentro solución. estoy creando un proyecto simple con hibernate siguiendo un ejemplo de netbeans.org y me indican que debo crear un metodo Helper en el que llame a la sesion actual. mi clase queda de la siguiente forma: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

importe todas las librerias y todo, incluso vi la clase de HibernateUtil y no sale este metodo de getSessionFactory().

alguna ayuda o forma de hacer lo mismo de una forma en que si funcione???

Quedo atento

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de hibernate nos obliga a tener siempre disponible una referencia al objeto SessionFactory para que cualquier clase pueda tener acceso al objeto Session y por lo tanto a todas las funcionalidades de Hibernate.

El problema de acceder al objeto SessionFactory es que cualquier clase podría necesitarlo por lo que deberemos hacérselo llegar de alguna forma.

Es por esto que se suele realizar una clase HibernateUtil que implementa el patron Singleton u otra tecnica, **esta clase no hace parte de la libreria de Hibernate ni mucho menos**, **esta clase la realiza cada quien para facilidad y modularidad**. Al parecer **tu clase HibernateUtil no tiene el metodo getSessionFactory**. Mira como realizar una clase Hibernate Util

```
 1: public class HibernateUtil {
 2:
 3:     private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
 4:
 5:     public static synchronized void buildSessionFactory() {
 6:         if (sessionFactory == null) {
 7:             Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
 8:             configuration.configure();
 9:             configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
10:             ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
11:             sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
12:         }
13:     }
14:
15:     public static void openSessionAndBindToThread() {
16:         Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
17:         ThreadLocalSessionContext.bind(session);
18:     }
19:
20:
21:     public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
22:         if (sessionFactory==null)  {
23:             buildSessionFactory();
24:         }
25:         return sessionFactory;
26:     }
27:
28:     public static void closeSessionAndUnbindFromThread() {
29:         Session session = ThreadLocalSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
30:         if (session!=null) {
31:             session.close();
32:         }
33:     }
34:
35:     public static void closeSessionFactory() {
36:         if ((sessionFactory!=null) && (sessionFactory.isClosed()==false)) {
37:             sessionFactory.close();
38:         }
39:     }
40: }
```

Como ves, la anterior clase tiene un objeto sessionFactory y tambien tiene un metodo get
Te dejo un ejemplo de como invocarla desde el Main.

```
1: public class Main {
 2:
 3:     public static void main(String[] args) {
 4:         HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory();
 5:
 6:         try {
 7:             HibernateUtil.openSessionAndBindToThread();
 8:
 9:             Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
10:             Profesor profesor = (Profesor) session.get(Profesor.class, 1001);
11:             System.out.println(profesor.toString());
12:         } finally {
13:             HibernateUtil.closeSessionAndUnbindFromThread();
14:         }
15:
16:         HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory();
17:     }
18: }
```

Referencias:

Asumi la clase del siguiente paquete [Clase HibernateUtil del paquete que utilizas](https://github.com/svn2github/ehcache/blob/master/patches/patched_2.2.1/src/main/java/net/sf/ehcache/hibernate/HibernateUtil.java)
Mas sobre HibernateUtil
[Lee acerca de HibernateUtil](http://www.cursohibernate.es/doku.php?id=unidades:07_arquitectura:01_hibernateutil)

Comment: Muchas gracias lei y busque respecto a lo que me comentaste y funciono así que ya puedo seguir practicando con hibernate. saludos

Comment: @cristian si esta respuesta te sirvió, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el icono de la parte superior izquierda de la misma.